# UIBezierPath Stroke (and Fill) in Swift

Tags: swift, uibezierpath

I'm struggling to find a way to stroke (and fill) a Bezier path in swift. Here's what I thought would work but doesn't.

```
var myBezier = UIBezierPath()
myBezier.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
myBezier.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0))
myBezier.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 50, y: 100))
myBezier.closePath()
UIColor.setStroke(UIColor.blackColor())
myBezier.stroke()
```

The line `UIColor.setStroke(UIColor.blackColor())` gives me this error in the console:

```
Playground execution failed: error: <REPL>:51:1: error: expression
resolves to an unused function UIColor.blackColor())
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The line `myBezier.stroke()` gives me this set of errors:

```
Jul 19 12:07:46 Computer-MacBook-Pro.local [20579] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jul 19 12:07:46 Computer-MacBook-Pro.local [20579] <Error>: CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jul 19 12:07:46 Computer-MacBook-Pro.local [20579] <Error>: CGContextSetLineJoin: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jul 19 12:07:46 Computer-MacBook-Pro.local [20579] <Error>: CGContextSetLineCap: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jul 19 12:07:46 Computer-MacBook-Pro.local [20579] <Error>: CGContextSetMiterLimit: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jul 19 12:07:46 Computer-MacBook-Pro.local [20579] <Error>: CGContextSetFlatness: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jul 19 12:07:46 Computer-MacBook-Pro.local [20579] <Error>: CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jul 19 12:07:46 Computer-MacBook-Pro.local [20579] <Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jul 19 12:07:46 Computer-MacBook-Pro.local [20579] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
```

In Objective-C, I would use something like this but, this is obviously not going to work in Swift.

```
[[UIColor blackColor] setStroke]
[myBezier stroke]
```

Any Sugestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`setStroke` is an instance method of `UIColor` and takes no parameters. Use

```
  UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
```

This means:

```
    var color = UIColor.blackColor()   //returns color
    color.setStroke()                  // setStroke on color
```

But you are doing opposite.

```
 UIColor.setStroke(UIColor.blackColor())
```

This means you are calling the class method `setStroke` of `UIColor`, and passing `blackColor`. `setStroke` is an instance method, not a class method, so you need a `UIColor` object, which is returned by `UIColor.blackColor()`.

**EDIT**

```
//MyPlayground.playground
import UIKit

class MyCustomView :UIView{


    //Write your code in drawRect
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        var myBezier = UIBezierPath()
        myBezier.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        myBezier.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0))
        myBezier.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 50, y: 100))
        myBezier.closePath()
        UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
        myBezier.stroke()
    }


}

var view = MyCustomView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

This will not give error for context

Comment: Thanks so much... The above does now seem to set the color and is demonstrated in the Playgrounds Assistant Editor but I do get the below error in the Console. This may simply be a xCode-6 beta issue though.

Comment: `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.`

Comment: are you in a graphics context like where you placed this code

Comment: @
Shannon Buckland where you placed the code it is in `drawrect:` or somewhere else?

Comment: @Shannon Buckland more help if you paste whole function

Comment: Not sure what you mean "in a graphics context". I'm just experimenting with Swift code in a .playground file which seems to have lower restraints on rendering code snippets. FYI, I'm just a hobby coder and my understanding of several languages probably only goes a little beyond superficial and I know how frustrating this can be for a coder with an in-depth knowledge.

Comment: This is not in a `func` it's just a snippet of code in an xCode playground.

Comment: Oh i see.Actually this code should be written in graphics context .You should place this code in UIView `drawRect` as bezer curves need to draw on something.They cannot be drawn on console.So you need UIView to draw these bezer curve

Comment: I've tried adding my Bezier path as a subview of a UIView but it says that UIBezierPath cannot be a UIView subview

Comment: You can not you have to make custom subclass of `UIView` and write this in `drawRect:` method.Follow this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH14-SW1for more understanding

Comment: follow this guide https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH14-SW1

Comment: Thanks! I think I have an understanding... I've got some reading to do! I will get back once I get a grasp on the resources you've provided.

Comment: @ShannonBuckland look for my edited answer and paste this code in your playground it will not give error

Comment: Thank you so much for you help and patience! Like everything, one solution usually leads to more questions (this is certainly true for me here), but the resources you have pointed me to have, and should continue to, answer most of those questions that arise. Thanks again for getting past my sticking point, as basic as it was.

Answer (score 2):

> In Objective-C, I would use something like this but, this is obviously not going to work in Swift.
>
> ```
> [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke]
> [myBezier stroke]
> ```

It's not obvious at all. In fact, it's false. If that code would have worked in Objective-C, then it will work in Swift. Translate directly:

```
UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
myBezier.stroke()
```

But of course you can't do any of those things, in Objective-C or in Swift, unless you are in a graphics context (e.g. `drawRect:` or UIGraphicsBeginImageContext).

Comment: @DilipTiwari I've asked you before, and now I ask you again: if you have a question, click Ask Question and ask a _question_. Please stop leeching your begging comments onto irrelevant questions and answers. Now I have requested a moderator to examine your behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.2:

```
//MyPlayground.playground
import UIKit

class MyCustomView :UIView{

    //Write your code in drawRect
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let myBezier = UIBezierPath()
        myBezier.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0))
        myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 100))
        myBezier.close()
        UIColor.black.setStroke()
        myBezier.stroke()
    }

}

var view = MyCustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```